# Apps that sync info between iOS app and mac

Tags: ios, macos, synchronization

Hey! I am wondering how for example some "to-do" apps sync info between mac and iOS apps? Do they use bonjour or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This really differs per app. Some indeed use Bonjour but others use the cloud or a custom protocol.

Comment: So is bonjour a good option if I am planning to make such feature in my app?

Answer (score 0):

They sync via a variety of methods, primarily implementing their proprietary solution (if not otherwise using iCloud and Core Data). Some use the Dropbox SDK, some use their own cloud servers, some use simpler document sharing and syncing via iCloud and so on.

Bonjour is only an option if you're on the same Wifi network - and even then it's unreliable as some routers need extra configuration to work with Bonjour. Bonjour is a bad idea in general as people are mostly out and about with their devices and expect their apps to sync back to the Mac without additional connectivity etc.